# Problem with WHERE clause matching on Arabic string Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a oracle 12g database in which I have some tables contain Arabic text. The datatype for those fields is NVARCHAR(n). 
when i execute this  code not fetch any rows

```
select * from  table_name where usages  ='سكني'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use N before string as follows:

```
select * from  table_name where usages  = N'سكني'
```